At boot: "Starting version 249.11-0ubuntu3.12", then hangs
My old Linux box, booting into an Ubuntu partition just says "Loading, please wait ...". then "Starting version 249.11-0ubuntu3.12" and hangs there forever.
I was able to start it in recovery mode, then tried to repair packages, but that resulted in  "No module named 'DistUpgrade' and dumped me to a root shell.  Assuming a recent update (possibly not completed properly) may have caused this, what can I do at the root shell to maybe clear this up?
